# I'm getting "TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE unrecognized archive format" when installing React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

When i try to install React Router Dom i get this error :

npm install react-router-dom@6

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm ERR! code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
npm ERR! TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lolod\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-06T22_29_09_099Z-debug-0.log
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong? Im running my react js application just fine.

PD: I tried reinstalling npm and restarting my pc.